# Friend function strange behaviour

Tags: c++, oop, friend

I'm learning C++ by myself and one of the programs that I made is sort of a school information system, it is not my first OOP program but this time I experience some strange behavior of a friend function.
I have a derived class `Student` which has a private member - static array of `Courses` objects, and finally the main container class `Class` which has a member - dynamic array of `Students` objects.

as you can see `avg` member of `student` is calculated using a friend function of `Courses` class (`calc_avg` receives an array of `Courses` sums it's grades and divides by course number), it works like a charm.
The problem starts once I try to calculate an average grade (`class_avg`) for a `Class` object - I use the same logic - create a friend function of `Student` (`class_avarage` that will have access to each students avg) that will receive an array of `Student` objects and it's size, add each students average grade and divide by array size - for some reason it receives and returns garbage values, I've been trying to fix it for 3 hours and I cant find the problem, help me if you can - here is the relevant code (independent derived classes are not included and output functions are minimized):

`main` //only container object creation and IO functions (all `.h` files included)

```
Class test1;
test1.input_class();
test1.output_class();
```

`Student.h`

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "Courses.h"
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Student : public Person
{
public:
    Student();
    void input_student ();
    void output_student ();
    friend float class_avarage (Student* array, int);
    ~Student();
protected:
private:
    Courses my_courses [6];
    float avg;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H
```

`Student.cpp`

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
//ctor
}
void Student::input_student ()
{
cout << "Please enter students info:" << endl;
input_info();
my_courses[0].input_grades ("Math");
my_courses[1].input_grades ("English");
my_courses[2].input_grades ("Science");
my_courses[3].input_grades ("History");
my_courses[4].input_grades ("Art");
my_courses[5].input_grades ("Sports");
}

void Student::output_student ()
{
int i;
cout << "Students info:" << endl;
output_info();
cout << "   Course  Grade" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    my_courses[i].output_grades ();
}
avg = calc_avg(my_courses, 6);
cout << "   " << "Average grade for student: " << avg << endl;
}
Student::~Student()
{
//dtor
}
float calc_avg (Courses* array, int size)
{
int i;
float sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum += array[i].grade;
}
return sum/size;
}
```

`Courses.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#ifndef COURSES_H
#define COURSES_H

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Courses
{
public:
    Courses();
    void input_grades(string);
    void output_grades();
    friend float calc_avg (Courses*, int);
    ~Courses();
protected:
private:
    string course_name;
    int grade;
};

#endif // COURSES_H
```

`Courses.cpp`

```
#include "Courses.h"

Courses::Courses() : course_name ("Default"), grade (-1)
{
//ctor
}
void Courses::input_grades (string temp_name)
{
course_name = temp_name;
cout << "Enter " << temp_name << " grade: ";
cin >> grade;
cin.get();
}
void Courses::output_grades ()
{
cout << "   " << course_name << ":    " << grade << endl;
}
Courses::~Courses()
{
//dtor
}
```

`Class.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Teacher.h"
#include "Student.h"
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class Class
{
public:
    Class();
    void input_class ();
    void output_class ();
    ~Class();
protected:
private:
    string class_name;
    Teacher class_teacher;
    Student* pupils;
    int students_number;
    float class_avg;
};

#endif // CLASS_H
```

`Class.cpp`

```
#include "Class.h"

Class::Class() : class_name ("A"), pupils (NULL), students_number (0), class_avg (0)
{
//ctor
}
void Class::input_class ()
{
int i;
//input class data
cin >> students_number;
cin.get();
pupils = new (std::nothrow) Student [students_number];
if (!pupils)
{
    cout << "Allocation failed!" << endl;
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < students_number; i++)
    {
        pupils[i].input_student();
    }
}
class_avg = class_avarage (pupils, students_number);
}
void Class::output_class ()
{
int i;
cout << "   Displaying info of class :" << class_name << endl <<
    "   Class average grade: " << class_avg << endl;
class_teacher.output_teacher();
cout << "   Number of students: " << students_number << endl << "   Students: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < students_number; i++)
{
    pupils[i].output_student();
}

}
Class::~Class()
{
//dtor
}
float class_avarage (Student* array, int size)
{
cout << size << endl;
int i;
float total = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    total += array[i].avg;
}
return total/size;
}
```

Comment: Too much code, whatever the error is, try to narrow the spot down.

Comment: -1: the code you throw at us is not focussed on the problem to be solved.

Comment: If allocation fails then your code goes on to call `class_avarage(NULL, students_number)` causing undefined behaviour. Change `new (std::nothrow)` to `new`, let the exception bubble up to where you want to handle it.

Comment: As far as I can see you do not actually create any instances of `Class`.  So in fact you have not shown enough code, you need to show the code that is creating and using `Class` objects. Since your `Class` has broken copy semantics, my guess would be that you are making copies of a `Class` resulting in trouble.

Comment: Removing `pupils` and `students_number`, and using `std::vector<Student>` instead, would solve a lot of problems in one fell swoop

Comment: @Matt McNabb - added main, only one `Class` object is created, it's input function is called, later it's output function is called.

Comment: I actually prefer to use dynamic allocation because in our course we are not allowed to use vectors.

Answer (score -1):

Why should anyone want to use friend functions? Just add simple getter for Cource.grade member and lasy getter for Student.avg. This will eliminate the possibility to get garbage instead of data.
Also, use std::vector and pass them throught std::vector&, not arrays and pointers.